# Youtube API, как запросить все видео с канала?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, request, youtube-api

Собственно как?
Использую Node.JS, и библиотеку "request" https://github.com/request/request
Я почитал документацию, максимально я могу запросить только 50 видео с канала, в ответе от апи-сервера, есть ключ nextPageToken, но не пойму как сделать цепочку запросов этого самого nextPageToken что-бы далее пройтись по всей цепи.

```
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${key}&channelId=${channelId}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50`;
```

Набросал вот такой код

```
request({url:url}, function(err, response, body){
    let data = JSON.parse(body);
    for(let i = 0; i < Math.fround(data.pageInfo.totalResults / maxResults); i++){
        let newUrl = url + '&pageToken=' + data.nextPageToken;
        request({url: newUrl}, function(err, response, body){
            newUrl = url + '&pageToken=' + JSON.parse(body).nextPageToken;
            console.log(JSON.parse(body).nextPageToken);
        })
    }
})
```

У канала +450 видео, не додумался до лучшего решения и беру результат первого запроса, и делю на максимальное кол-во запрашиваемых видео, получаю допустим 9-10, далее это получается 10 проходов за цикл, и в теории каждый запрос должен обновлять переменную `newUrl` и после, опять обращаться к апи серверу за новыми данными, и новым nextPageToken.

Как быть?

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы получаете ответ от ютуба то да, в нем должен быть этот самый nextPageToken. И в очередном своем запросе его нужно указать.

Допустим есть запрос

queryUrl = "[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=3&playlistId=PLфывYaAMфывmoK1r6jH740g22l4F&key=фывывфывфывфывфывY](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=3&playlistId=PL%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2YaAM%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2moK1r6jH740g22l4F&key=%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2Y)";

новый и каждый следующий будет такой

queryUrl = queryUrl + "&pageToken=" + nextPageToken;

т.е. чтобы получить все 450 видосов нужно сделать 9 запросов. И они это специально сделали т.к. они наверное принципиально не понимают зачем вам сразу 450 видосов. И это нормальная практика отдавать данные частями.

Сделали запрос, сохранили результат, сделали запрос, сохранили результат с прибавлением к сохраненному и т.д.  450 видосов ну сек 8 примерно.